# How to implement Windows service kind of infrastructure in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have limitations to host Windows Services in my web hosting provider. But i need run small task frequently.

Do we have any other framework/api which provides similar infrastructure like "Windows Services" from ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

I think it will better if you can use FireDaemon. If you can create a console application, then the filedemon will be able to run it frequently similar to Windows service.

http://www.firedaemon.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ASP.NET 4, you can have your app pool always running, then have a timer going, and whenever that time elapses, run your process:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can start a thread using the Application Start event in the Global.asax to do the scheduled job. It is not as robust solution as a Windows Service but it is good enough in most cases.